# Google Places API returns 404 error with UTL_HTTP

Tags: oracle, api, rest, plsql, google-places-api

I am currently trying to geocode addresses using Google map API and Google Places API. I call both api using UTL_HTTP.begin_request 
However, I am getting 404 error from places api but I can get the result from google maps api geocoding. Below is a snippet of the utl_http that calls the api

```
 UTL_HTTP.SET_PROXY (v_proxy);
  --SSL certIFication for google API
  UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET (v_walletLoc, v_walletPass);
  --SET CHARSET for proper chinese results
  UTL_HTTP.SET_BODY_CHARSET ('AL32UTF8');
  req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request (v_url, 'GET', 'HTTP/1.1');

  UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (req, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  --response of API call AKA results
  BEGIN 
    DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (v_xml, FALSE);
    resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response (req);
    putLine('RESPONSE CODE: ' || resp.status_code);
    LOOP 
        --insert results into v_txt
        UTL_HTTP.read_text (resp, v_text, 32767); 
        v_xml := v_xml || v_text;
    END LOOP;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_of_body THEN
     UTL_HTTP.END_response (resp); 
  END;
```

The url that goes into the utl_http for places api are

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=PRINCE+EDWARD+road&sensor=false&key=<My key>
```

The response I get is a html page that tells me the 404 error. The requested URL is not found. 
If I were to enter the google geocode url which is as below, I would get the result I wanted in the form of xml.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=PRINCE+EDWARD+road+WEST+MONG+KOK&sensor=false
```

For more information:

- I am calling this from an oracle server using PLSQL.
- This is meant for batch processing of addresses in order to clean addresses
- I use places api for those rubbish addresses which might only have building names instead of a street level address

Comment: Just an FYI, I'm seeing this as well, but with a ColdFusion HTTP call. I can enter the URL in the browser and it works fine.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?